# Webpack not picking up some CSS files

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, vue.js, css-loader

I am using Vue.js 2.5.15, Webpack 4.12.0, css-loader 0.28.11, ASP.Net Core 2.1 in Visual Studio 2017.

I started with the Visual Studio asp.net core template project for Vue and Typescript. My preferred approach is to have individual smaller css files inside each component folder under ClientApp. This way the .vue, .ts and .css files are all right next to each other.

However, when I run the app, only some of the css files have made it into Main.js. I want to figure out why - with the exact same setup - some of the css files in these subfolders are included and some are not. Everything is identical as far as I can tell in terms of how they are referenced but some css files just refuse to be picked up. Here are more details about my setup:

Folder structure: [Component Folder Structure Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnTOW.png)

NPM packages: [NPM Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWgLe.png)

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoader = require('vue-loader');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.ts' },
        mode: "development",
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.vue$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'vue-loader', options: { loaders: { js: 'ts-loader' } } },
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
            }
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoader.VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production')
                }
            }),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

In main.js that is generated in my dist folder, the css for 'settings' is included but not for 'monkeys'. Does anybody have an idea why this might be?

Monkeys.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="monkeys-container">
        I love monkeys!!!!!!!!
    </div>
</template>

<style src="./monkeys.css"></style>
<script src="./monkeys.ts"></script>
<!--<style>
    @import './monkeys.css';
</style>-->
```

In settings.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="settings-container">
        <grid v-if="settingsloaded" v-bind:headernames="headernames" v-bind:coltypes="coltypes" v-bind:datarows="datarows"></grid>
        <div v-else>{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<style src="./settings.css"></style>
<script src="./settings.ts"></script>
```

Ideally I don't want to include any other npm packages, I just want to understand why webpack is not being consistent. As a workaround, I could use import statements at the top of my boot.ts to manually import each css dependency but that wouldn't help me work out why my setup half works at the moment. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning the above approach and used Vue cli 3 instead. This helps to scaffold the Vue project with the latest dependencies and removes the need for as many config files. It also includes built-in support to scaffold a Vue project that uses TypeScript.

I also moved from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio Code. Now I'm using .vue files where all the html, typescript and css are in a single file for each component. Much better!

So to summarise, I recommend using vue-cli-3: https://cli.vuejs.org/

And also Visual Studio Code instead of the full Visual Studio.

Happy coding!